# Cannot untag AWS resources

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, tagging, aws-mediaservices, aws-mediaconnect

I am trying to untag deleted AWS resources with the **resourcegroupstaggingapi**.

I am listing my resources with the following command :

```
aws resourcegroupstaggingapi get-resources --tag-filters Key=special_project --tags-per-page 100
```

Then, I am trying to untag resources with :

```
aws resourcegroupstaggingapi untag-resources --resource-arn-list arn:aws:mediaconnect:ap-northeast-1:XXXXXXXXXXX:flow:1-XXXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXX:flow-created-by-mr_ --tag-keys special_project
```

I always got the following error:

```
{
"FailedResourcesMap": {
    "arn:aws:mediaconnect:ap-northeast-1:XXXXXXXXXXX:flow:1-XXXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXX:flow-created-by-mr_": {
        "StatusCode": 400,
        "ErrorCode": "InvalidParameterException",
        "ErrorMessage": "Unrecognized service for tagging"
    }
}}
```

Here is the example from the AWS doc :

```
aws resourcegroupstaggingapi untag-resources \
--resource-arn-list arn:aws:s3:::awsexamplebucket \
--tag-keys Environment,CostCenter
```

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.
Any help would be highly appreciated.

### Additional information :

Tagging AWS MediaConnect resources work with the MediaConnect API, but doesn't work with the **resourcegroupstaggingapi**.
On the other hand the **resourcegroupstaggingapi** can list AWS MediaConnect resources.

Comment: The error says `Unrecognized service for tagging`. Are you sure that you can use Resource Group Tagging on this type of resource? How was the tag added? Did you use `aws resourcegroupstaggingapi tag` to create the tag? I would recommend trying that first.

Comment: @ John Rotenstein Thanks for your reply. I added the TAG when I created the resource. TAGs were added with the `MediaConnect` & `MediaLive` api. I will try to add TAG with `resourcegroupstaggingapi`. The strange thing is I can list resources with `resourcegroupstaggingapi`

Comment: @ John Rotenstein Apparently, MediaConnect resources cannot be tag/untag by the resourcegroupstaggingapi . https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ARG/latest/userguide/supported-resources.html#supported-resources-console